# Problems with Google+ Pages API Activities.Insert

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-apis-explorer, google-plus-domains

I have access via the partner program to the Google+ Pages API, and I'm trying to post to my domain account. I am successfully able to post to pages that I manage via my domain account, as well as posting to my personal G+ page, but I keep getting this error when posting to my domain G+ account:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Calls to this method must be made by or on behalf of a Google+ Page."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Calls to this method must be made by or on behalf of a Google+ Page."
 }
}
```

I have confirmed I have all scopes included. To test, I'm using the command line example Google provides:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: OAuth <access token for Google+ Page>" -d "{'object':{'content':'Test message'}}" -X POST https://www.googleapis.com/plusPages/v2/people/<pageid>/activities
```

Anyone have an idea why this would happen?

Comment: It's an API for Pages, you can't post to it as your account.

Comment: Why then would it work with posting to my personal G+ account?

Comment: In the question you said your "personal G+ page".

Answer (score 0):

> "Calls to this method must be made by or on behalf of a Google+ Page."

The user making this call must have access to the domain account.

Make sure sure that you are properly [Authencated](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/)